# On the definition of hyperbolic conservation law

Tags: mathematical-physics, conservation-laws

There is a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law) and an [article by A. Bressan](http://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/clawtut09.pdf) that introduce the notion of hyperbolic conservation law.  I'm not used to this area, so I have some questions about the definition.  I will stick to the one dimensional case.

Let $y : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and
let $j : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  A **one dimensional conservation equation**
is the equation
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial (j \circ y)}{\partial x_1} = 0$$

So here is my basic questions: What are the types (domain and codomain) of $y$ and $j$?  What is the quantification: i.e. is it, for any $y$ and $j$ of those types that satisfy the differential equation, we say that $y$ and $j$ form a conservation law. --?  Or do $y$ and $j$ need to have other dependencies as well.

Also, if you want to leave any other comments regarding one dimensional conservation laws -- please do.  I would love to learn more.

Comment: Conservation laws I'm familiar with are typically of the form $\partial_tu+\partial_xf(u)=0$ where $f(u)$ is the flux of $u$. In some cases (e.g., density, $u=\rho$), $f(u)=u v$ where $v$ is the velocity, but it's not always this simple (e.g., momentum conservation law in fluid dynamics).

Comment: Thanks!  There is a mismatch in terminology.  The wiki article calls f the conserved quantity and u the density, whereas the Bressan article calles u the conserved quantity and f the flux.  Can flux be defined without regard for u, as a function in its own right?

Comment: @JonathanGallagher Your comment is a bit unclear because you can take any function which is not a variable of $u$ and make it a function of $u$ by multiplying it -- for example, consider $\partial_t u + \partial_x (f(v) u) = 0$ which is no fundamentally different than $\partial_t u +\partial_x f(v,u) = 0$. Kyle's comment may be unclear a bit because there's no requirement that flux depends solely on the conserved quantity. For instance, you can do: $\partial_t u + \partial_x c(x) u = 0$, where $u$ is the conserved value and $c(x)$ is the wavespeed as a function of $x$.

Comment: Which Wikipedia article? It should be that $u$ is the conserved quantity. The fluxes I normally work with do depend on $u$.

Comment: @tpg2114: I would probably argue that your flux is $f(u,x)=c(x)u$, so your flux is still dependent on $u$. Perhaps that is just me, though.

Comment: From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law.   "y(x,t) is called the density of the conserved (scalar) quantity"  They are using y where I am using u.

Comment: @tpg2114: What is the definition of flux, and for a one dimensional system, what is the domain and codomain?

Comment: @KyleKanos: When you say flux depends on u, that seems to indicate that flux takes functions as input, which I am more than happy with, but means that I have the typing, or at least the domain of flux wrong...?  For example, we could speak of "simple multiplicative flux": f(u,v) = v*u.

Comment: Wikipedia is using the Jacobian, so with my variables: $\partial_x f(u) = (\partial_uf)(\partial_xu)=A(u)\partial_xu$. $u$ is a vector and $f(u):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The claim is that $u$ depends on $x,t$ thought right?  Doesn't that make $u$ a function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30313/discussion-between-jonathan-gallagher-and-kyle-kanos).

Comment: I'm not allowed in chat (banned site at work), but I always have treated $u$ as a vector of values; this may not be 'mathematically rigorous' but it is how I view it.

Comment: Thank you, this discussion is quite helpful! Treating u as a vector can be dualized to a linear functional, and perhaps that is what is going on?  Things seem to work out that way in examples, but I am still struggling to grasp the abstract definition.

Comment: @KyleKanos that's the point I was trying to make - if you want to define a Flux as a function independent of $u$ then it is also possible to write it as a function dependant on $u$. So the original comment about "can a flux be defined without regard to u" isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You asked a couple of questions, so I'll try to take them in order.

> What are the types (domain and codomain) of $y$  and $j$?

Mathematically, I think you are on good ground to choose any domain and codomain for $y$.  The domain of $j$ must include the domain of $y$, of course, and it should not depend directly on $x_1$ or $x_2$.  The codomain needs to be consistent with $y$ to the extent that it makes sense to add a time derivative of $y$ with a gradient of $j$.  From a physics point of view, in most cases expect $y$ to be a function of space and time.  Beyond that you have no restrictions in general - although the specific physical scenario may imply additional requirements.

> What is the quantification: i.e. is it, for any y  and j  of those types that satisfy the differential equation, we say that y  and j  form a conservation law. --? Or do y  and j  need to have other dependencies as well.

Yes, if they satisfy the equation, then they form a conservation law.  I don't think that there's more to it than that. I'd take the equation to *define* a conservation law.

> Also, if you want to leave any other comments regarding one dimensional conservation laws -- please do. I would love to learn more.

Here are some assorted facts / concepts, which apply more generally than 1D:

- Every conservation law corresponds to a symmetry.  This is closely connected to Noether's theorem, which you can look-up.  A "symmetry" in this case is more general than the every-day examples like "left-right symmetry."  It means that some physical law is does not depend on some identifiable quantity.  Gauge invariance from electrodynamics is an example of this broader type of symmetry.  The action for EM does not change when you make a gauge transformation.
- Another similar but different concept is a constraint.  A constraint must be satisfied at each point in space and time. The conserved quantity is only conserved in a more global (I'd like to say "integral") sense since whatever stuff is represented by your $y$ is allowed to move to another place in space - It just cannot be created or destroyed.  Using EM again, $\nabla \cdot E = \rho/\epsilon_0$ is a constraint since it's satisfied everywhere and for all time.  Each constraint (trivially) implies a conserved quantity - In this case $\partial_t (\nabla \cdot E - \rho/\epsilon_0) = 0$.  Converted to the notation of your question, in this case $y = \nabla \cdot E - \rho/\epsilon_0$ and $j(y) = 0$.

Comment: Do you know of any "good" reference?  You are sure that $j$ doesn't need to be a functional?

Comment: I'll think about the reference. In the meantime - By "functional" I understand something that maps a function to a scalar. Are you using it that way? If so, then, in your notation, $\partial (j \circ y)/\partial x_1 = 0$ since the dependence on $x_1$ goes with $y = y(x_1,x_2)$ and would be "lost" when $j$ maps $y$ to a number. I'm unclear what you mean. @JonathanGallagher